# C# Create high score text file

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm creating a little game (Memory) that should contain a high score list.
The project is a windows grid app using XAML and C#.
This is the last solution I saw and it sounds logical to me:

```
private void New_Score(int score, string name)
{
    string filename = "highscore.txt";
    List<string> scoreList;
    if (StorageFile.Exists(filename))
        scoreList = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
    else
        scoreList = new List<string>();
    scoreList.Add(name + " " + score.ToString());
    var sortedScoreList = scoreList.OrderByDescending(ss => int.Parse(ss.Substring(ss.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1)));
    File.WriteAllLines(filename, sortedScoreList.ToArray());
}
```

If I try this in my window8 project. The `File` class is not found.

I'm searching for hours but I can't find a solution that fits for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `File` class is in `System.IO` namespace.

Therefore, on top of your file, add this reference:

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @sceed Can you upload your full solution to some cloud drive and publish a link?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/memory_1 you can find the "new score" method in the "rules.cs" lines 258-269

Comment: Hello @sceed , with Visual Studio 2015 Professional, it compiles **without errors!** So maybe it has to do with your setup. Which programming environment are you using?

Comment: Hello @George , I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: at the university i am using the 2015 Enterprise Version, same Problem here

Comment: @sceed That's really strange - on my machine, it compiles without errors.